# Hacking Google AJAX Search Result page

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, greasemonkey, google-ajax

I am a novice developer, and have created a simple greasemonkey script to modify content at Google Search result page. Scripts loads fine at first page. but as user goes to second page (or searches for new query) - the modifications are not reflected.

I guess this is because of ajax, as Google now loads results using ajax. I read other answers here, suggesting use of `DOMNodeInserted` and other tricks, but nothing works.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: I guess yes! There are 'tons' of greasemonkey scripts for doing this. But, none of them work with recently introduced Ajax results

Comment: You say "suggesting use of DOMNodeInserted ... but nothign works". Please show some code you tried that doesn't work, also consider https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events , i.e. DOMSubtreeModified .

Answer (score 0):

Listening to events like DOMNodeInserted will work if used correctly. [Other useful events can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events).